# HTML - Preload Key Request - Can this syntax be improved?

Tags: html, optimization

I am attempting to construct a Preload Key Request for site optimization. I am getting a message that I need to construct a preload key so I created the following element and added it to my header:

```
<link rel=”preload” href="http://bluegrassmediagroup.com/wp-content/plugins/hustle/assets/hustle-ui/fonts/hustle-icons-font.woff2” as=”font” type=”font/woff2” crossorigin>
```

Even after creating this element, I am still getting the same message that the key needs to be constructed. Can this html element be improved in any way? I am stumped.

Comment: "I am getting a message" — from where?

Comment: Don't use curly quotes `”`. Use either `'` or `"`

Comment: The message is from the speed optimization site

Comment: What speed optimization site? You need to be explicit and descriptive - what is the message exactly?

Comment: I am getting the following message on google page speed insights when trying to optimize my site: "Consider using <link rel=preload> to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load."

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo (as highlighted by  j08691). Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/) which would have detected this error.

Comment: what is the typo? I changed it to being encloded by ' on both ends and I am still receiving the same message